panda read_excel cannot load excel on serverless
We have a notebook used to run well on virtual server. There is an excel file stored in Data Lake Gen2 which is mounted to DataBricks.
Below code is running well before switch to serverless:
pd.read_excel('/dbfs/mnt/folder/myExcel.xlsx')

But it is not working after switch to serverless. Error is:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Other notebooks reading and writing dataframe are working on serverless so I think the mountpoint is correct. The only thing not work is read_excel. How should I work around it?

Try this code df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \     .option("header", "true") \     .option("inferSchema", "true") \     .load("dbfs:/mnt/folder/myExcel.xlsx") .  com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.5
is the  package to install.

You can try the below code to achieve your requirement.
First install the openpyxl and then read the excel file using this.
pip install openpyxl

import pandas as pd
pdf=pd.read_excel("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/myexcel.xlsx",engine='openpyxl')
pdf.head()


Also, as a workaround, first read the excel file as pyspark dataframe and then convert it into pandas dataframe as suggested by @JayashankarGS.
Install the com.crealytics.spark.excel library in the cluster from maven.
df=spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("your_filepath")
pdf=df.toPandas()
pdf.head()


